# Deleting multiple pattern simultaneously

Tags: error, global-command

I would like to execute multiple deletions. The problem when a pattern is not found all deletions are cancelled. I used the e flag to tell vim the not founding a pattern is not an error, but it still does not work.

The command looks like the following:

```
:g/pat1/de | g/pat2/de | ... | g/patn/de
```

Comment: When there are too many patterns, you can put them in a file and do `:%!grep -vf patternfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a careful look at the syntax of `:global`: there's a pattern, and a command. We also know from `:help :bar` that everything after the pattern is the command, including `|`. Lastly, the `:delete` command can be abbreviated at any point up to `:d`, so `:de` is just the regular delete command.

Thus, your command really means "on each line with `pat1`, do `delete` (nested global) on each line with `pat2`, do ….

At `:help :global` we see

> When the command is used recursively, it only works on one line.

You have a few options:

- Separate the commands. This can be done with `:execute`, like `:execute 'global/pat1/delete' | execute …` (abbr.: `:exe 'g/pat1/d' | exe …`). Or type each command individually, hitting enter. The former might require a `:silent` modifier somewhere to avoid "Patter not found."
- Combine the patterns: `:global/pat1\|pat2\|…/delete`. If you can use `\v`, I recommend it (then the separator becomes `|` instead of `\|`, but pay attention to other changes in `patN`).

Lastly, you *can* chain substitutions (though again I would combine patterns here):

```
:%substitute/.*pat1.*//e | %substitute/.*pat2.*//e | …
```